# How to Execute Powershell stored in Azure storage using Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have a ps1 file created which will do some provisioning activity. I have upladed that file in Stroage account. Now i have created another automation account with a runbook, I want to call the ps1 file stored in Storage account from the Automation runbook. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the .ps1 file to the runbook temp folder, then call it.

The test.ps1 file stored in blob storage, it's content like this:

```
param([string]$p1,[string]$p2)

Write-Output "***this is from a test ps1 file***"
Write-Output $p1
Write-Output $p2
```

Code like this:

```
    #create the context to authenticate with azure storage
    $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName your_storage_name -StorageAccountKey "your_storage_key"

    #download the .ps1 file to runbook temp folder
    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "your_blob_container" -Blob "test.ps1" -Destination $env:temp -Context $context | Out-Null

    #execute the powershell
    &"$env:temp\test.ps1" -p1 "my name is p1" -p2 "i'm p2"
```

The result:

[image]